# Split single list into multiple list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which holds json objects like this

```
a =[{"User": "Ram","Product": "Soap","Price": "25"},
    {"User": "Ramesh","Product": "Shampoo","Price": "5"},
    {"User": "Ramesh","Product": "powder","Price": "35"}]
```

Now I want to split this single list into multiple list like this

```
a2 = [
      [{"User": "Ram","Product": "Soap","Price": "25"}],
      [{"User": "Ramesh","Product": "Shampoo","Price": "5"}],
      [{"User": "Ramesh","Product": "powder","Price": "35"}]
     ]
```

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this solution, I am new to python.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you _want_ these one-element lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap each item in brackets:

```
a2 = [[item] for item in a]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just out of curiosity is there a simpler way like this to do the vice-versa

Comment: Sure; `a3 = [item[0] for item in a2]`.

Answer (score 3):

Do like this,

```
[[i] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution,

```
new_a = map(lambda x: [x], a)
```

Output

```
[[{'Product': 'Soap', 'User': 'Ram', 'Price': '25'}], [{'Product': 'Shampoo', 'User': 'Ramesh', 'Price': '5'}], [{'Product': 'powder', 'User': 'Ramesh', 'Price': '35'}]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a more verbose way to do it without the list comprehension from Avinash's answer.

```python
def list_split(a):
    sp = []
    for element in a:
        sp.append([element])
    return sp

a2 = list_split(a)
```

Comment: The readability of comprehensions is a matter of perspective/opinion.

Comment: Correct, that does not read the way I intended it to, replace readable with verbose. Apologies.